# How can I serialize functions at runtime in Clojure?

Tags: function, serialization, clojure, edn

Is there a way to serialize functions at runtime in Clojure?  I'd like to be able to send stateless (but not pure) functions over the wire in a serialized format (probably edn, but I'm open to anything).

---

## For example...

If I run `prn-str` on a function, I don't get what I expected/wanted.

```
user=> (def fn1 (fn [x] (* x 2)))
#'user/fn1
user=> (def data {:test 1 :key "value"})
#'user/data
user=> (defn fn2 [x] (* x 2))
#'user/fn2
user=> (prn-str fn1)
"#object[user$fn1 0x28b9c6e2 \"user$fn1@28b9c6e2\"]\n"
user=> (prn-str data)
"{:test 1, :key \"value\"}\n"
user=> (prn-str fn2)
"#object[user$fn2 0x206c48f5 \"user$fn2@206c48f5\"]\n"
user=>
```

I would have wanted/expected something like this:

```
user=> (prn-str fn2)
"(fn [x] (* x 2))\n"
```

or, maybe,

```
user=> (prn-str fn2)
"(defn fn2 [x] (* x 2))\n"
```

Comment: In the repl. `(source fn2)`. Digging in a couple levels, copy to get the source in string version can be seen `(println (clojure.repl/source-fn 'clojure.repl/source-fn))`. At first glance it seems pretty opaque, but maybe could be modified to given a serializable version of a func. My guess is isn't won't work in the most general case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At some point it ceases to be Clojure, so the expectation that we can arbitrarily round trip from source to machine instructions and back is a little bit off.

We should be able to serialize a function to a byte array and send that across the wire though. I suspect you'd need to grab the function's java.lang.Class object and then pass that through a [java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/ClassFileTransformer.html) to get the bytes. Once you have those you can pass them through to the friendly [java.lang.ClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) on the remote jvm.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to use `quote` or `'` to prevent evaluation and `eval` to force evaluation:

```
(def fn1 '(fn [x] (* x 2)))
(prn-str fn1) ;;=> "(fn [x] (* x 2))\n"
((eval fn1) 1) ;;=> 2
```

Comment: But what if you already have a function, not its source code, and you want to serialize the function itself? I'm pretty sure Datomic supports that; how can you do it in Clojure?

Comment: @SamEstep Once a function is compiled, you don't have access to the source code, just the function object. However, vars can have metadata describing where the source can be found. This is how `source` works.

Comment: I'm completely aware of that. That's not what I was asking; I specifically said that I was asking about a case where you *don't* have access to the source code.

Comment: I would inply from Michael’s answer that the only way then would be to disassemble into Java and translate that into Clojure, but that’s some hassle I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Flambo, a Clojure wrapper for Spark, uses the [serializable-fn](https://github.com/technomancy/serializable-fn) library to serialize functions (which Spark requires).  Sparkling, another wrapper for Spark, uses native Clojure functions through [this Java abstract class](https://github.com/gorillalabs/sparkling/blob/develop/src/java/sparkling/serialization/AbstractSerializableWrappedIFn.java) that implements the Java interface Serializable.

Comment: Note that Sparkling's "serialization" of Clojure functions is really serializing two symbols: the namespace, and the name of the fn. In deserializing them, it requires the namespace and returns a reference to the fn. That is, the body of the fn is not serialized at all. The Clojure code is expected to be baked into an uberjar and launched on the cluster (so all the code already exists on every worker). Dynamically defining Clojure functions and passing them to a Spark operation isn't supported.

Comment: https://github.com/helins/fdat.cljc

Answer (score 1):

You have basically two choices:

- pass source code (s-expressions stored as clojure data)
- pass jar files and load them on the other side.

for the first option you **save the source** at the time the function is compiles (almost always when it is defined) and then pass the same source expression to the other computer and let it compile the same thing. so first you might make a vector of expressions:

```
(domain-functions '[(defn foo [x] x)
                    (defn bar [y] (inc y)]
```

then you can store this into a database and each client can pass it to `read` and then they will all have the same functions.

The second option depends on the fact that each time you define a function it produces a class file in the /target directory and then loads it. You can then syncronize this directory and load them on the other side. This approach is of course completely crazy, though people do crazy stuff around here. I recommend the first approach

---

And as a personal note:

I'm doing this now with datomic, and I have adopted the practice of putting the git-hash into the function name using a macro so I know absolutly for certain that when I call a function, I'm getting the same function I see in the editor. This brings peace of mind when running many instances that all pull from the same DB.

Comment: From what I've heard, your second approach is basically how Hadoop works.  But I agree that it sounds insane.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `clojure.repl/source`.

```
(with-out-str (source filter))
```

to get a string, or

```
(read-string (with-out-str (source filter)))
```

to get a clojure list.

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't a good way, and for good reason simply shipping a function to another computer or storing it in a DB can cause lots of problems, not the least of which is that that function may require other functions that aren't on the other end.

A much better idea is to stick with data. Instead of writing the function, write the name of the function as a event, and then that even can be translated later by whatever is reading your data. Stick with data, that's the idiomatic way.

Comment: But this is LISP.  What happened to the promise of "code is data, data is code"?

Comment: Many times this promise is interpreted to mean merely that the language is homoiconic and macros & `eval` are supported.  Implementations don't often interpret it to mean "we provide extremely dynamic introspective access to compiler mechanisms", probably because providing these features is typically a performance killer.

Comment: Sure @BlueJ774, but you can't just take a fragment of data and ship it somewhere and expect it to run. There's things like local state, VM revisions, language verions, etc. that can all cause problems. Code is also opaque once it's compiled, and so it makes a very poor communication method. Networks are designed to transfer data, and we should use them for transferring data, not code.