# Serializing anonymous functions

Tags: clojure

I'm writing a Genetic Algorithm. To help play with the settings during runtime, I'm trying to save the settings (mutation rate, cross chance, fitness function...) to disk. That would allow me to modify the file, then read the file occasionally to update the settings at runtime. Getting input from the console would be easier, but Intellij's ability to take input is atrocious and proved too difficult to use, so this is the route I'm trying.

My problem is this: The settings are represented by a record. Many of the individual settings are numbers, so they're easy to save to disk. Some settings however are functions, which don't save nicely:

```
(defrecord Settings [
                 gene-set
                 sequence-length
                 fitness-f])

(with-out-str (pr
              (->Settings #{1 2 3}
                          10
                          #(count %)))))
```

Yields:

```
"#ai.genetic_algorithm.genetic_algorithm2_2.Settings{:gene-set #{1 3 2}, :sequence-length 10, :fitness-f #object[ai.genetic_algorithm.genetic_algorithm2_2$eval776$fn__777$fn__778 0x1b30c92 \"ai.genetic_algorithm.genetic_algorithm2_2$eval776$fn__777$fn__778@1b30c92\"]}"
```

For the most part this is fine, except for the way the fitness function is represented. If I try to read the file back in:

```
(read-string
  (with-out-str (pr
                  (->Settings #{1 2 3}
                              10
                              #(count %)))))
```

I get:

```
ai.genetic-algorithm.genetic-algorithm2-2=> RuntimeException No reader function for tag object  clojure.lang.LispReader$CtorReader.readTagged (LispReader.java:1245)
```

And I only get this error when trying to save/read a function. I'm guessing it has no way of knowing what I'm asking it to read the function as, so it barfs.

Is there any way of reliably saving anonymous functions to file?

And yes, I know `read-string` is potentially dangerous. I'm using it solely for a personal project though, so I'm not worried about the vulnerability.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I serialize functions at runtime in Clojure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38753960/how-can-i-serialize-functions-at-runtime-in-clojure)

Comment: @OlegTheCat Whoops. I don't know how I didn't find that. Thanks. That seems awfully complicated for what I need it for. I might just need to nix saving the functions, although that complicates things as well :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your code to instead of generating a function and then later extracting that function from the namespace to save it to a file, you rather generate the expression for the settings and save the expression to a file right then. Then use the result of loading that file as the new state.

```
user> (let [new-config '{:gene-set #{1 2 3}
                        :sequence-length 10
                        :fitness-f (fn [x] (count x))}]
           (with-open [w (clojure.java.io/writer "/tmp/config.edn")]
             (binding [*out* w]
               (pr new-config)))     
           (load-file "/tmp/config.edn"))

{:gene-set #{1 3 2}, 
 :sequence-length 10, 
 :fitness-f #function[user/eval111126/fn--111127]}
```

when you are defining the new fitness function to save, generate it as a sequence of symbols and save that sequence before it is compiled into a function class. Let the only time it is compiled be when it is loaded so you know it will always be something loadable. This will catch bugs.

If you find yourself wanting to mechanically generate compositions of these you may want to consider giving them names an only saving the composition order in the config.