# Clojure: How to Serialize a Function and Reuse it Later

Tags: clojure

```
(defn my-func [opts]
  (assoc opts :something :else))
```

What i want to be able to do, is serialize a reference to the function (maybe via `#'my-func` ?) to a string in such a way that i can upon deserializing it, invoke it with args.

How does this work?

#### Edit-- Why This is Not  a Duplicate

The [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38753960) asked how to serialize a function body-- the entire function code. I am not asking how to do that. I am asking how to serialize a reference.

Imagine a cluster of servers all running the same jar, attached to a MQ. The MQ pubs in `fn-reference` and `fn-args` for functions in the jar, and the server in the cluster runs it and acks it. That's what i'm trying to do-- not pass function bodies around.

In some ways, this is like building a "serverless" engine in clojure.

Comment: I asked the same question awhile ago, and from what I was told, there is no easy way. I think what I settled on was using a map holding keyword/function pairs, then I serialized the keyword. When I unserialized it, I just needed to give the keyword to the map to retrieve the function. Of course, that means you must know every function you need to serialized ahead of time, but I only had like 4 functions I needed it for, so it worked fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I serialize functions at runtime in Clojure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38753960/how-can-i-serialize-functions-at-runtime-in-clojure)

Comment: I dont want to serialize the body, just the reference.

Comment: Serializing "just the reference" doesn't make sense. That's not serializing. If you want to just pass the reference around within the same JVM, then you don't have to serialize at all. If you want to move it outside the JVM and then revivify it in some other JVM, you need to serialize it (and that's really hard).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Weirdly, a commit for serializing var identity was *just* added to Clojure yesterday: https://github.com/clojure/clojure/commit/a26dfc1390c53ca10dba750b8d5e6b93e846c067

So as of the latest master snapshot version, you can serialize a Var (like `#'clojure.core/conj`) and deserialize it on another JVM with access to the same loaded code, and invoke it.

```
(import [java.io File FileOutputStream FileInputStream ObjectOutputStream ObjectInputStream])

(defn write-obj [o f]
  (let [oos (ObjectOutputStream. (FileOutputStream. (File. f)))]
    (.writeObject oos o)
    (.close oos)))

(defn read-obj [f]
  (let [ois (ObjectInputStream. (FileInputStream. (File. f)))
        o (.readObject ois)]
    (.close ois)
    o))

;; in one JVM
(write-obj #'clojure.core/conj "var.ser")

;; in another JVM
(read-obj "var.ser")
```

Comment: Wut. That's awesome, and weirdly timed. This definitely would have been helpful a few months ago.

Comment: Might be worth adding the comment Mr. Hickey added to that commit: "Note - serialization only supports reconnecting the Var identity on the deserializing end. Neither the value in the var nor any of its properties are serialized". Probably obvious, but worth noting. Not relevant to the current question, but it may be of help for someone else coming here for a similar reason.

Comment: what would a code example of this be like? i wish i could read the java source but i'm not on that level yet!

Comment: Added example code to answer (all of the read/write code is just standard Java serialization and should work with most Clojure objects).

Answer (score 5):

As suggested on the comments, if you can just serialize a keyword label for the function and store/retrieve that, you are finished.

If you need to transmit the function from one place to another, you essentially need to send the function source code as a string and then have it compiled via `eval` on the other end.  This is what Datomic does when a Database Function is stored in the DB and automatically run by Datomic for any new additions/changes to the DB (these can perform automatic data validation, for example).  See:

- http://docs.datomic.com/database-functions.html
- http://docs.datomic.com/clojure/index.html#datomic.api/function

As similar technique is used in [the book Clojure in Action  (1st Edition)](https://www.manning.com/books/clojure-in-action) for the distributed compute engine example using RabbitMQ.